# Envelope detection in frequency domain with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, frequency-domain

I need to compute the envelope of a spectrum in MATLAB. Is there a specific function that can do it?  I saw the function

```
[yupper,ylower] = envelope(x,np,'peak')
```

but i'm not sure this one can be used in the frequency domain. The image below shows the result I would like to obtain (green line).

[image: spectrum envelope]

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate about this function `[yupper,ylower] = envelope(x,np,'peak')`  or if possible share its code, most probably you can  get the green curve by changing the order of cepstrum env. calculation.

Comment: That is a built-in MATLAB function, you can find more [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/envelope.html). The cepstral envelope is an estimation, I'm interested in computing the real envelope. @arpit

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I think you can use linear prediction for your calculation. this link might be helpful for you http://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Spectral_Envelope_Examples.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I'll try the LPC method. Many thanks for your answers! @arpit

Comment: @Daniel. Perhaps the material at the following web page may help you: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/938.php

Answer (score -1):

you can use envspectrum.
a good example is shown [in this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/predmaint/ug/Rolling-Element-Bearing-Fault-Diagnosis.html#RollingElementBearingFaultDiagnosisExample-9).